# How do I force a youtube iframe with fixed aspect ratio to always stay inside container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a CSS problem which is driving me absolutely crazy that I have tried to solve for two days now. Basically I have an iframe embed from youtube which is in a container that gives it a fixed aspect ratio with the following CSS.

```
.iframe-container {
  padding-bottom:56.25%;
  position:relative;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

What I want is for the Youtube player to resize to stay completely inside the browser window regardless of what shape it has. In the following shape of the window, it works as intended (black square is the window, red square is the video with its fixed aspect ratio of 16:9)

[image: css1]

When I shrink the window to be thinner, the video player shrinks as intended, staying completely within the window:

[image: css2]

What I WANT to happen when I instead make the window short and wide, is for "the same" thing to happen in the other direction, i e the top and the bottom of the window (container div) forces the video player to shrink so that there is space betwen the left and the right edge and the video player, just like there was space between the top and the bottom of the window and the video player when the window was tall and thin. Expected behaviour:

[image: css3]

But what ACTUALLY happens is that the video player becomes enourmous, still touching the left and the right edge, and the whole video no longer fits in the window:

[image]

How the heck do I solve this?

My HTML:

```
<div className="modal-bg"> 
  <div className="modal-box">
    <div className="modal-youtube-container">
      <div className="modal-youtube-video">
        <div className="iframe-container">
          <iframe 
            src={"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + mediaUrl.slice(32, 43)}
            title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" 
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
            allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the complete css:

```
.modal-bg {
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 99999; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* Black w/ opacity */
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.modal-box {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.modal-youtube-container {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    //max-height:100%;
}

.modal-youtube-video {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;   
}

.iframe-container {
  padding-bottom:56.25%;
  position:relative;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `vh(viewport height)` and `vw` instead of percentage?

So you would set the iframe `height(vh)` to `100vh` and then the `width` to `auto`?

Comment: I have tried many combinations of percentatges and vw and vh but I just can't figure out how to get it to behave like I want. Could you be more specific?